# How do I pass an onClick output to the calling class

Tags: java, android

A class called `CardBrowser` instantiates an object which contains the following method.

```
public void MakeClassButtons(Button b) {
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CardBrowser.CardListTemp = new ListViewManager().Generate(v);
            }
        });
}
```

I want to set a variable in `CardBrowser` called `CardListTemp` when the button is clicked. Right now I'm making the `CardListTemp` variable a global static, but I'm pretty sure this is a bad idea since it's not easily unit-tested. `CardListTemp` changes very often. This is only an example but there are a lot of buttons and the output generated depends on `View v`.

Comment: use an interface maybe?

Comment: I guess there is no simple way to do it? Like using `out` or `ref` in C#?

Comment: Use a "callback-interface" it's similar the same you do it if you work with fragments

Comment: interface is the JAVA way of doing it.And you won't regret doing it.

Comment: @ManuZi Ah, I figured it out.